# Why are exploding HHO bubbles louder then pure HHO?

Tags: acoustics, home-experiment, explosions

We tried my electrolyzer with a friend today, we filled a small bottle with HHO gas, and set it on fire. It was loud but not a big deal, like a firecracker. Then we added some soapy water and created HHO bubbles instead of filling the bottle with HHO underwater. Then we lit the bubbles and it exploded so loud that for a while all we heard was just ringing. It was way too louder than when before, same gas same bottle, we even tried it twice with same result.
Im wondering why is it so unbelievably louder. I thought that maybe the sound just traveled in a different way, because the bottle was turned in the opposite way (towards the ceiling instead of towards the floor), but im not sure.

Comment: 'HHO gas' is a term usually used in the context where a small device, aka the 'electrolyser' is supposed to reduce miles to the gallon duel consumption of cars. It's a well known and demonstrated scam: http://www.nlcpr.com/Deceptions10.php

Comment: I'm still wondering what "HHO" is *supposed* to be, scam or not. Water vapor is $\mathrm{H_2O}$, hydrogen is $\mathrm{H}_2$, oxygen is $\mathrm{O_2}$. There is no HHO molecule.

Comment: @ChrisWhite It is a fringe science term for [oxyhydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxyhydrogen), more precisely a mixure of 8 parts (by mass) $\text O_2$ to one part $\text H_2$ such that hypothetically its combustion converts all of both to $\text H_2\text O.$

Comment: @ChrisDrost: it's not 'hypothetical': 2 mol $\mathrm{H_2}$ and 1 mol $\mathrm{O_2}$ do *really* combine to 2 mol $\mathrm{H_2O}$ but the scam is to pretend a car engine can provide the 'HHO gas' by electrolysis and then somehow save fuel. Violates thermodynamics, that one.

Comment: Could it be that you're igniting more gas when you burst the bubbles? Give more details. I imagine you're letting a lot of hydrogen leak out in the first case.

Comment: Please don't blow up bottles of anything. Generally, exploding things without knowing what you're doing is not a good idea.

Comment: Also, if your ears are ringing it means you've just permanently damaged your hearing. I'd suggest being cautious with your ears, as you only get one pair.

Comment: @Gert: they *can* combine to that but they *don't usually under combustion*. 100% conversion efficiency of generally requires slow, controlled processes; combustion is a fast uncontrolled one. You can get around this by adding more of one of the components (which is done in practice; the mass ratio is lower than 8:1 to guarantee that the oxygen is burned) and accepting the loss in the other one.

Comment: @ChrisDrost: I'd really like to see how much unreacted $\mathrm{H_2}$ and $\mathrm{O_2}$ is left over after you ignite a stoichiometric mixture of the two. That reaction is very fast, even in non-explosive conditions (burners e.g.).

Comment: @ChrisDrost: *"100% conversion efficiency of generally requires slow, controlled processes;"* in much of chemistry is also not true. Perfectly stoichiometric mixtures of reagents in aqueous medium often run to completion in the mere blink of an eye.

Comment: @ChrisWhite "There is no HHO molecule"  Right.  It's a "magnecule", held together by "magnecular bonds".  :-/

Comment: $$ 2H_2O=2H_2+O_2 ~not~ HHO$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas you might want to consider or explore:

### 1. Bottle

You take a 1 litre water bottle made of PET and filled with water. You invert it and place it into a tank of water over electrodes that are producing oxygen and hydrogen gas. You collect the mixture of gases until all the water has been displaced from the bottle. You take the bottle from the water tank and move it to another location, you apply a source of ignition (e.g. a match) to the open mouth of the bottle.

- You lost some gas while moving the bottle from the tank to another location (it was replaced by mixing with nitrogen and other gases in the surrounding air.
- The shape of the bottle limits the spread of the ignition through the gas inside the bottle, the ignition spreads from the opening and travels along the length of the plastic bottle.
- The bottle itself resists the expansion produced by the burning gases and perhaps limits the rate at which the reaction proceeds

### 2. Bubbles

You dispense with the bottle, add some detergent to the water and allow the oxygen and hydrogen to form bubbles at the surface

You ignite the bubbles.

- Some of the hydrogen and oxygen does not form bubbles but is invisibly present around the bubbles. This leads you to underestimate the volume produced
- you are not good at visually estimating 1 litre of bubbles. You have more than 1 litre of collected gas.
- The bubbles are not contained in a (moderately) rigid container. This means the reaction can spread faster - producing a more concentrated (louder) sound wave.

### In General

You will see I have had to invent a description of your procedure because you only described it in very vague terms. You did not describe in detail the apparatus you used or the procedure you followed. you did not explain how you measured and verified the volumes of gas involved.

I have made a number of hypotheses - you should also. Some of these hyptheses will turn out to be false on testing. I would think about how you can test all these hypotheses. I would think about how I can make good records of everything done. I would ask myself what sort of controls I can introduce. I would think about how I could make a more objective measurement of the loudness of the explosions and how to fix the distance of the measuring equipment from the site of explosion.

### Hint

"way too louder than when before" and "so unbelievably louder" are not SI units :-)